# Change Visual Studio community build language

Tags: visual-studio

I am having problems with Visual Studio community 2015 and localization of my app. For the first time i have a need to create app on another language and after building and deploying, some characters arn't showing correct. My project is Ionic project in Visual studio and can't find a place where to change language option for built application. Anyone can help me out?

```
1>  ------ buildCommand: prepare
1>  ------ platform: Android
1>  ------ cordovaPlatform: android
1>  ------ configuration: Debug
1>  ------ cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------ projectName: ionictarot
1>  ------ projectSourceDir: C:\Users\...
1>  ------ npmInstallDir: C:\Users\...
1>  ------ language: en-US
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out, thou my index.html was saved by my charset encoding, my other pages where with different charset saved.